# How do I mock active record finders with rspec-fire?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm mocking an active record finder with [rspec-fire](https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire):

```
user_class = fire_class_double('User').as_replaced_constant
user_class.should_receive(:find_by_email).with(email).and_return(user)
```

When I run this, rspec-fire complains that the User class does not implement find_by_email.

The [readme](https://github.com/xaviershay/rspec-fire#doubling-class-methods) says that it's possible to double class method by subclassing FireDouble. However, I can't figure out how to do this. Furthermore, it seems the FireDouble class has already been replaced with a [FireDoublable](http://rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-fire/RSpec/Fire/FireDoublable) module.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't directly possible because the AR finders aren't actually defined as methods in the normal way. Same deal for column accessors. The easiest way to enable this is to explicitly define the methods you want to use:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.find_by_email(*args); super; end
end
```

As an aside, [AR finders have been deprecated](https://github.com/rails/activerecord-deprecated_finders).

Comment: Thanks! I thought the deprecation only covered the old-style finder option hashes but not dynamic finders.